# MKMapView Crashes When Adding Annotations

Tags: ios, xcode, annotations, mkmapview

**Problem**

I am having a problem with my MKMapView.When I initialize it and try to add a couple annotations, the app crashes, giving my a SIGABRT and claiming that I have an "uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'" I have messed around with NSLogs and my code and found that it occurs whenever I call [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation]. I have tried both annotations individually and the app still crashes.

**Code**

Here is the code I am using for my MKMapView

```
IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView; //these are in interface
DisplayMap *thing1; //yes, I have @properties too, and I synthesize them
DisplayMap *thing2;

-(void) initMap //called in viewDidLoad after [super viewDidLoad]
{
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 0;
region.center.longitude = 0;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES]; 
[mapView setDelegate:self];

thing1.title = @"thing1";
thing1.subtitle = @"is here"; 
thing1.coordinate = region.center; 

thing2.title = @"thing2";
thing2.subtitle = @"is somewhere"; 
CLLocationCoordinate2D thing2Coord = {0.005,0.005};
thing2.coordinate = thing2Coord;
[mapView addAnnotation:thing1];
[mapView addAnnotation:thing2];
}

//and my DisplayMap code
//the .h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

@interface DisplayMap : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
NSString *title; 
NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title; 
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
//the .m
#import "DisplayMap.h"

@implementation DisplayMap
@synthesize coordinate,title,subtitle;

-(void)dealloc{
[title release];
[subtitle release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**Theories**

I tried to isolate initMap so that it is called before any of the rest of my app loads. I have other processes running later, but they should not be active at this point because they have not been initialized yet. I imagine the problem could have something to do with my initialization of the MKMapView itself, or in my Displaymap properties. Xcode can't detect it, whatever it is, and I'm not really sure what the error I'm getting even means.

Comment: Where do you initialize thing1 and thing2?

Comment: As has been mentioned in a previous comment and an answer, you aren't initialising your objects. I suggest you take some time to learn the basic debugger controls (setting breakpoints, stepping through code and examining variables) as this will help you locate bugs like this. The clue is in the error message you were getting "attempt to insert nil". Learning these techniques will make your coding a LOT quicker than messing with `NSLog`s all over the place

Comment: oh gosh this is embarrassing, I had thought that when you @synthesize objects it took care of alloc/initializing them. All I had to do was add thing1 = [[DisplayMap alloc] init] to get rid of the error.However, now I am having the problem that the annotations are not showing up on the screen, what can I do about that?

Comment: By the way, do you know that the region.center (0,0) and coordinates you are specifying (0,0 for thing1 and 0.005,0.005 for thing2) are in the Atlantic Ocean?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina yeah, those coordinates I put have no significance on purpose. I use the actual coordinates in my project, but wanted to keep them hidden from the internet for privacy's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, it doesn't look like you are ever instantiating `thing1` and `thing2`.

Try adding these lines at the beginning of your init function.

```
 thing1 = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
 thing2 = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
```

Just because these members are properties doesn't mean that they are auto-initialized.

Comment: thank you, haha I figured it out after I saw the first comment and felt so silly for not noticing that earlier.